# How to automatically run ffmpeg command

Tags: cron

I am recording a daily TV show with the ffmpeg code. I want to run this ffmpeg command at a certain time of the day. What should I add to the ffmpeg code to do this?
I want to record the TV program at 4am. At that time I could not wake up to do. And handmade is also inaccurate.

Thank you

Comment: You should look into [cron jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). These allow you to run a specific command at a given time, which should allow you to do what you're after.

Comment: I do not know programming. I only used a few ffmpeg commands on win7.